# How to build a react project without minify the node modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build, minify

I've been working on a project, but when I try to build it I got the following error:

```
Failed to minify the code from this file:
    ./node_modules/emailjs-com/es/utils/validateParams.js:1:7
```

I am using `craco` to build the project. I have researched about this error, but I was not able to make any of the solutions I found work on my case.

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my-portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "-": "^0.0.1",
    "@craco/craco": "^5.9.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "emailjs": "^3.5.0",
    "emailjs-com": "^3.2.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.5",
    "save-dev": "^0.0.1-security"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "gh-pages": "^3.2.3",
    "postcss": "^7.0.36",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.0.2"
  }
}
```

I would like to know if there is a way to build it without executing any minification, or if it is really required, how to solve the minification that I am having when trying to minify my code.